# casting ArrayList.toArray() with ArrayList of Generic Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting, arraylist

A difficult question which I'm close to giving up all hope on.  I'm trying to make a
function, but am having problems getting `ArrayList.toArray()` to return the type I want.

Here's the minimal example that demonstrates my problem:

```
public static <T> T[] test(T one, T two) {
    java.util.List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(one);
    list.add(two);
    return (T[]) list.toArray();
}
```

Normally I'd be able to use the form `(T[]) list.toArray(new T[0])` but there are two added difficulties:

1. Because of the covariance rules I cannot typecast arrays, `(T[]) myObjectArray` gives a `ClassCastException`
2. You cannot create a new instance of a generic type, meaning I cannot instance `new T[]`.  Nor can I use clone on one of the elements of `ArrayList` or try to get its class.

I've been trying to get some information using the following call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(test("onestring", "twostrings"));
}
```

the result is of the form `[Ljava.lang.Object;@3e25a5` suggesting that the typecast on the return is not effective.  strangely the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test("onestring", "twostrings").getClass());
}
```

comes back with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at patchLinker.Utilities.main(Utilities.java:286)
```

So my best guess is that it think's it's a String array label wise, but internally is an Object array, and any attempts to access brings that inconsistancy out.

If anyone can find any way of working around this (since the two normal workarounds are denied to me) I'd be very greatful.

K.Barad
JDK1.6

---

Edit

---

Thanks to Peter Lawrey for solving the initial problem.  Now the issue is how to make the solution apply to my less trivial example:

```
public static <T> T[] unTreeArray(T[][] input) {
    java.util.List<T> outList = new ArrayList<T>();
    java.util.List<T> tempList;
    T[] typeVar;
    for (T[] subArray : input) {
        tempList = java.util.Arrays.asList(subArray);
        outList.addAll(tempList);
    }
    if (input.length > 0) {
        typeVar = input[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return (T[]) outList.toArray((T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(typeVar.getClass(),outList.size()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] lines = { { "111", "122", "133" }, { "211", "222", "233" } };
    unTreeArray(lines);
}
```

The result at the moment is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
at patchLinker.Utilities.unTreeArray(Utilities.java:159)
at patchLinker.Utilities.main(Utilities.java:301)
```

I'm still doing some tests to see if I can get any more useful information than this, but at the moment I'm not sure where to start.  I'll add any more information I get as I get it.

K.Barad

---

edit 2

---

Some more information now.  I've tried to build the array manually and transfer the items in elementwise, so I'd be typecasting as T, rather than T[].  I found an interesting result:

```
public static <T> T[] unTreeArray(T[][] input) {
    java.util.List<T> outList = new ArrayList<T>();
    java.util.List<T> tempList;
    T[] outArray;
    for (T[] subArray : input) {
        tempList = java.util.Arrays.asList(subArray);
        outList.addAll(tempList);
    }
    if (outList.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        outArray = input[0];// use as a class sampler
        outArray =
                (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(outArray.getClass(), outList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < outList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "  " + outArray.length + "   " + outList.size() + "   "  + outList.get(i));
            outArray[i] = (T) outList.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(outArray.length);
        return outArray;
    }
}
```

I still get the following output:

```
0  6   6   111
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String
at patchLinker.Utilities.unTreeArray(Utilities.java:291)
at patchLinker.Utilities.main(Utilities.java:307)
```

Does this mean you can't write to a `T[]` even if you manage to create one indirectly?

Comment: I suggest sticking with collections and leaving behind old school reference arrays.

Comment: Would love to, but there are times when you have no choice in the matter.  Backward compatability always implies that something is backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your second code sample is caused because of your `T[] typeVar`: Input is a two dim array, so `input[0]` will return a one dim array (a String[], instead a String, as expected).

If your are to convert your `List<T>` to a `T[]`, you'll need a `T typeVar`,

To fix it:

```
public static <T> T[] unTreeArray(T[][] input) {
    java.util.List<T> outList = new ArrayList<T>();
    java.util.List<T> tempList;

    if (input.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }


    T typeVar=null;
    for (T[] subArray : input) {
        if(typeVar==null && subArray.length>0) {
            typeVar=subArray[0];
        }
        tempList = java.util.Arrays.asList(subArray);
        outList.addAll(tempList);
    }

    return outList.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(typeVar.getClass(),0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] lines = { { "111", "122", "133" }, { "211", "222", "233" } };
    String[] result=unTreeArray(lines);

    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println(result.getClass());

        //added for completion:
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(result));

}
```

The resulting output:

> [Ljava.lang.String;@5a405a4 class
>   [Ljava.lang.String;
>   [111, 122, 133, 211, 222, 233]

Comment: Ok, definately a moment of madness hitting me.  Of course you pass it the element not the array type or what is the point?  Thanks for that, it seems all is working at last.

Comment: Happens a lot. Sometimes we look from too close to our own code to find the hidden bugs :)

Comment: Question to @TomasNarros What if the input array is empty, then typeVar will be left NULL thus you've got a NullPointerException. How to return an empty list in that case?

Comment: If the input can be null, you should check at the very first place, changing  `if (input.length == 0)` for `if (input !=null && input.length == 0)`

Answer (score 4):

toArray() always returns an object array.

To return an array of a specific type, you need to use toArray(Object[]).

To provide the correct type for the array argument, you need to use the specific class or in this case use reflections.

try

```
 return (T[]) list.toArray(Array.newInstance(one.getClass(), list.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried that but it gave the rather ambiguous error of: 
The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Object) 
I did a few manual checks, I can invoke getClass() on the instances, so I suspect that it's beccause newInstance() returns an object

Comment: You should add a cast conversion on the Array.newInstance method result. i.e: list.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(one.getClass(), 0))

Comment: @K.Barad It needs another cast. It also has problems if the two objects are of different types. Or if the returned array is modified by the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten that converting Object => T[] is valid, it's only Object[] => T[] that isn't.  Well now to test if it works in my (slightly less trival) real method.  Thanks for the help, hopefully this has it solved

Comment: No luck.  It's possible I've made some daft error, I've been seeing this code for too long without a break.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an array of a generic type parameter. The simple reason is the fact that java usually erases the generic type information at runtime so the runtime has no idea what T is (when T is a generic type parameter).

So the solution is to actually get a hold of the type information at runtime. Usually this is done by passing around a `Class<T> type` parameter but in this case you can avoid that:

@peter's answer looks good and i would use it :).

```
return (T[]) list.toArray(Array.newInstance(one.getClass(), list.size()));
```

Comment: Aye, I've spent more than a few hours of searching reading all the (admittedly quite good) reasons why generics wouldn't let me get an easy solution.